# How to hide SexyTooltip in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use SexyTooltip in my swift project. 
I have this code:

```
func showTooltip(prefix: Int?){
        var description = ""

        description = setProductIconTitle(prefix: prefix)

        let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,  NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor: .white]
        let greetingsText = NSAttributedString(string: description, attributes: myAttribute)

        let greetingsTooltip = SexyTooltip(attributedString: greetingsText, sizedTo: view, withPadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 5, 10, 5), andMargin: UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20))
        greetingsTooltip?.dismiss(inTimeInterval: 2)
        view.addSubview(greetingsTooltip!)

        greetingsTooltip?.present(from: iconView1, in: view, withMargin: 10, animated: true)
    }
```

This code works correctly. I would like to see only one hint / tooltip at one moment.
After clicking on another button - all previous hints / tooltips must be hidden.

How to do it?

Comment: After glancing at the section on "Dismissal" on the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/calm/SexyTooltip), I'm guessing `dismiss` or you could us the `dismissInTimeInterval` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
func showTooltip(prefix: Int?){

    for toolView in view.subviews {
        if toolView is SexyTooltip {
            toolView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    var description = ""
    description = setProductIconTitle(prefix: prefix)
    let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,  NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor: .white]
    let greetingsText = NSAttributedString(string: description, attributes: myAttribute)

    let greetingsTooltip = SexyTooltip(attributedString: greetingsText, sizedTo: view, withPadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 5, 10, 5), andMargin: UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20))
    greetingsTooltip?.dismiss(inTimeInterval: 2)
    view.addSubview(greetingsTooltip!)

    greetingsTooltip?.present(from: iconView1, in: view, withMargin: 10, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I have error: let greetingsTooltip = SexyTooltip! - Expected member name or constructor call after type name

Comment: try updaed answer